Random and Regular Freezing on MacBook Pro Mid 2010 running Ubuntu 24.04
I have just installed Ubuntu 24.04 on a MacBook Pro (Mid 2010).
Unfortunately I am getting regular freezing of the mouse and system. The only option is to turn the power off and restart the computer.
If I run sudo dmesg I get a lot of the following errors but I do not know if they are the cause of the freezing:
[   66.256770] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: 00100000 [] ch 3 [001fa70000 gnome-shell[1509]] subc 3 class 8597 mthd 1304 data 1d1c1b1a
[   66.256789] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: DATA_ERROR 00000012 [RT_LINEAR_WITH_ZETA]
These 2 messages are repeated regularly.
Is there a way I can work out what is causing the freezing? ie. logs of some type?
I have run the RAM test in the grub menu and the RAM passes the tests.
The other OS installed (which is Mac OS 10.13 High Sierra) works flawlessly so it is something within Ubuntu that is causing the freezing.
Hope someone can help.
Regards,
fbagnato

Thanks to the help provided on the #ubuntu IRC channel users I have a solution:
Setting the grub setting to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset" fixes the freezing.
Since I introduced that fix I experimented with the nouveau parameters and found another workaround which is a better solution as it still leaves the original video drivers loaded (where as the setting nomodeset replaces the original video drivers with the standard VGA driver).
Setting the grub setting to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nouveau.NvMXMDCB=0" fixes the freezing.

BTW nomodeset does not replace the driver it just does not use it. It is still installed in the OS.
